# How to address undefined offset 0 in wordpress's query.php when using get_post()

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress, I am using :

```
$posts=get_posts($args)
foreach($posts as $post){
   //do stuff
}
```

However, when there is no posts I get

> undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wrDTC\wp-includes\query.php on
>   line 2859

I have tried using `if($posts){}` but the notice still comes up.  How do I prevent this notice other than turning off error messages in php?

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply use the $posts as name of vars in the loop.

"$posts" is used in the query of wordpress as global and must be an array.

If you choose to name you var $posts, this result into an undefined offset 0 because your $posts do not have offset 0. remember, you just reset it.

Answer (score 1):

use Something like this...

```
  if(!empty($args) && count($args)>0){
    $posts=get_posts($args)
    foreach($posts as $post){
       //do stuff
    } 
    }
```

Comment: It's not the foreach that's triggering the Notice, it's actually the `get_posts()`.  When I remove all the foreach code, the notice is still there.

Comment: `get_posts()` is a function, not a variable, so how can it be empty?

Comment: Thanks.  $args is always set though.  I set it manually - `$args=array(
      'post_type' => 'event',
      'institution'=>'university');`

Comment: I reckon it must be an in built wordpress problem with query.php that I can't address unless I edit that file.

Answer (score 0):

try defining the offset in your $args i.e. ('offset' => 1) and instead of using the usual {} try using hooks and "endforeach;"

My foreach statements in wordpress dev are structured like:

```
<?php foreach($myPosts as $post) : setup_postdata($post) ?>

      <?php the_title(); ?>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      // etc
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```